# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dat.gui". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I want to add `dat.gui` library to use with three.js when ever I include the library it shows that error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dat.gui". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Similar error was shown with three.js library but

The code I use to import the library is :
`import * as dat from 'dat.gui';`

Comment: use `import * as dat from './dat.gui';`